# How to download a file in bash from a download PHP script?

Tags: bash

For example, a file named nerdtree.zip that can be download by running this link in browser:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian-based distros, you usually have wget available. On RHEL-based distros, you usually have curl.

This SuperUser question does a good job talking about making sure you get the right filename and some good examples.

https://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected